# Excel Formula to Count How many Forward Slashes (/) in Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to tell me how many forward slashes (/) I have in a cell.

The cell contains a blue hyperlink path to a folder.

I have tried a Len-Len(Substitute) formula, but it is not working because it returns `0`. My expected result is > 0.

The cell with the hyperlink is `B6`. The cell with my reference character (/) is `C6`.

My attempted formula is in cell `D6`.

```
=LEN(B6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B6,C6,""))
```

With:

- `B6` = `Z:\01 Project folders by PAG number range\@PAG Files 0001 to 0035\0001 Wadden Village_Wandle Park Village, Croydon\`
- `C6` = `'/`
- `D6` = `=LEN(B6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B6,"/",""))`

`D6` returns `0`

There are clearly several forward slashes in the path. I need a solution that will return the right value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace:

```
C6 = '/
```

with:

```
C6 = '\
```

Comment: Thanks Gaz Student. I feel like a tool. Took me 15min to write the question. Knew the solution was easy. I'm blushing now.

Comment: @DasalKalubowila you are not the first... :) been there, done that.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gary's Student posted before, I think his solution is the best way for you to achieve what you need in this instance. I am going to include the following, as it is a solution to your title question and hopefully this may help someone in the future.

```
Dim count as Integer
For i = 1 to Len(B6)
    If Mid(B6,i,1) = "/" Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i
return count
```

What we are doing is iterating through the cell value B6 in character increments of 1 from the first character to the last to count the number of forward slashes.